# Does Blender have a Wayland backend?

Tags: linux, development

I'm working on trying to submit a bug for an issue while running Blender 2.78c under [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)), and need to know if Blender has a Wayland backend, or if it is still using X11 via Xwayland when running under a Wayland session?

Comment: Before filing a bug report, make sure to test against the latest buildbot build, and not some old release.

Answer (score 9):

Blender now supports Wayland natively.
**Update** (2022-10-11): [Wayland is now enabled in daily builds](https://code.blender.org/2022/10/wayland-support-on-linux/) and is on track to be included in 3.4.

---

Blender 2.90 includes an [experimental Wayland backend](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/More_Features) when compiled with the corresponding flag. You can view which flags blender was compiled with when executing `blender --version` and you should be looking for `WITH_GHOST_WAYLAND`.

BTW you can easily test if an application is running under XWayland by starting `xeyes` and moving you mouse cursor above the window. If the eyes are still following the cursor the application uses XWayland

Comment: Wow... `xeyes`.. takes me back 25 years, under X11 on UNIX....

Answer (score 3):

As of today, not yet. You can do a simple query in the blender source repositories to verify: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/

However, there has been some work to make it happen: https://github.com/walac/blender-wayland